# Find a value in a Javascript Map

Tags: javascript

How do I find the first occurrence of a particular value in a Javascript `Map`? For example:

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set("a", "b");
m.set("c", "d");
m.set("e", "f");
m.set("g", "f");

// Then I want to do something like this:
m.find_value((v) => v === "f");
```

Ideally it would return the key and value as a tuple (2-element array), i.e. `["e", "f"]`.

Obviously this is trivial to code manually with a for loop, but is there any neater built in way?

Comment: Use the `.entries()` method and then `.find()` (the Array method).

Comment: `.entries()` does not return an `Array`.

Comment: It returns an Iterator object, which works as an array.

Comment: And before you suggest it, no I do not want to make my application unnecessarily slow by turning the map into an array just to search through it.

Comment: That's what your own answer does though?

Comment: No it doesn't. It uses `for of` to iterate through the map. It never turns the map into an array. And iterators do not work as arrays as far as I can tell.

Comment: Calling `m.entries()` most definitely creates an array.

Comment: [It most definitely doesn't!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries)

Comment: Ah. Well, I stand corrected. That's actually pretty cool and good to know.

Comment: I just wonder why you used `.insert` ... instead of `.set`

Comment: Oops... it's called `insert` in some other language I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a better way than writing it myself, like a commoner.

```js
function find_map_value<K, V>(m: Map<K, V>, predicate: (v: V) => boolean): [K, V] | undefined {
  for (const [k, v] of m.entries()) {
    if (predicate(v)) {
        return [k, v];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set("a", "b");
m.set("c", "d");
m.set("e", "f");
m.set("g", "f");

Map.prototype.find_value = function (predicate) { 
  return Array.from(this.entries())
    .find(([, v]) => predicate(v)) }

// Then I want to do something like this:
const result = m.find_value((v) => v === "f");

console.log(result)
```